# I can't install pip and other essentials

Tags: kali-linux, python, python3

When I try to install `pip` using `apt` by this command: `sudo apt install python-pip` it replies:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-pip
```

It also happens with pip3.

```
┌──(aja㉿aja)-[~/Desktop/minecraft java] 
└─$ sudo apt install python3-pip 
[sudo] password for aja: 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree... Done 
Reading state information... Done 
Package python3-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package. 
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or 
is only available from another source 

E: Package 'python3-pip' has no installation candidate
```

I am using Kali Linux.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't install pip and other essentials

The `python3-pip` is available in Kali repositories. Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` is misconfigured.

Use the following commands:

```
echo "deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Comment: it worked. thanks

Comment: done. thanks for your support

Answer (score 3):

The `python-pip` is no longer shipped in current releases of Debian or [Kali](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/python-pip); you can install the Python 3 version with

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Comment: it says 
┌──(aja㉿aja)-[~/Desktop/minecraft java]
└─$ sudo apt install python3-pip

[sudo] password for aja: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package python3-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3-pip' has no installation candidate